# Store Country, City and User info using mongoose and nodejs MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema, relationship

I want to use mongodb on my new project. That is first time, im using mongodb. In relational databases i was saving datas like:

```
tbl_country > id,name,created_at,etc..
tbl_city    > id,country_id,name,created_at,etc...
tbl_user    > id,name_surname,city_id,etc...
```

In this schema i can find a city's country, a user's country, etc... via using foreign keys.

Which way do you suggest to create a schema like this in best performance by nodejs w/ mongodb ?

Answer (score 1):

You can still use foreign keys when you create your schemas. Please check this schemas as examples you have given.

```
var CountrySchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  created_at: Date
});

var CitySchema = new Schema({
  countryName: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Country' },
  created_at: Date
});

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name_surname: String,
  city: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'City' }
})

mongoose.model('Country', CountrySchema);
mongoose.model('City', CitySchema);
mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

and when you fetch data, you have to use 'populate' method. For instance:

```
City.find()
populate('countryName', 'name') // It will bring only name field
.exec(function(err, cities) {
})
```

Btw. _id s are automatically created by mongo for each data. So you do not need to add id field into your schemas. Hope it helps. Good luck

Comment: I read some articles they says that it decreases performace ? Is it true ?

Comment: it depends on how to use it. If you just store country Name in your schema and you do not use your country schema, you do not need to use Reference Id. You can simply add subdocument into your schema. Like new Schema({ country: { name: String, code: Number } }) or just new Schema({country: String}). In this case, it is not necessary to use 'refId'. It decreases performance. Besides, you might have read some documents which are old posted. Since mongo has been using widely, It has developed itself a lot. So, you dont need to worry about performance as people thought inbeginning stage of mongo.